# Why doesn't this Python regex pattern return a result?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have struggled for a while and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. It must be something silly.

```
 text = 'I need this'
 word = 'need'
 prog = re.compile('\\b%s\\b'%word, re.IGNORECASE)
 result=prog.match(text)
```

But `result` is `None` implying there was no match. Why?

(I want to identify if the word occurs in the text if and only if it is a stand-alone word surrounded by what is listed as the Python boundries indicated by `\b`)

Comment: `re.match` looks at the **start** of the string, use `re.search` to find the match anywhere.

Comment: That's it. Strong documentation reading skills on my part (sarcasm). I was looking for the problem in the wrong place.